# How to check if a string is a substring of another, without using large ResultSets?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, memory-leaks, resultset

I am trying to write a webprice comparison software in java. I have a database which already has a lot of products type number (like 'ASD01'). And I have another database, that has the products type number like this: 'somethingASD01something'.

I want to check if database#2 contains the string in database#1. And delete the rows, where it not contains. I tried to solve it, as selecting both db in a result set, and compare them in the java code, but they are too large and using too much memory.

I found the LOCATE() method in mysql, which tells me what I want, but I still have to use the database#1 as a ReultSet, or are there any other ways to iterate through rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you should be able to delete the records you don't want with straight SQL...

If you want to delete records from DB2 that are **NOT matches** to a table in DB1, then a LEFT JOIN would be the approach... DB2 LEFT JOIN DB1 on your string comparison, then delete any DB2 record where there isn't a DB1 match:

```
DELETE `DB2`.`TableTwo`.*

FROM `DB2`.`TableTwo` a
LEFT JOIN `DB1`.`TableOne` t

on a.FieldFromTableTwo LIKE CONCAT('%', t.FieldFromTableOne, '%')

WHERE t.FieldFromTableOne IS NULL
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, it looks like you don't want to delete the matches, you want to delete records from DB2 that are NOT matches to something in DB1.. hmm, I'll revise.

Comment: `a.FieldName LIKE = "%ASD01%"` is not going to be fast. It has to full scan the `a` table.

Comment: If you want though that operation only once (and delete some of the rows), then I don't think that should worry you.

Comment: True, it won't be fast. But it's not clear whether he needs something to run just once or on demand. It's the simplest answer I can think of, and may be just what he needs.

Comment: Yes, and probably faster than `LOCATE()`.